# undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So when I run my application using `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`it gives me the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `devise' for Install (call 'Install.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)
```

In my gemfile, I already added `gem 'devise'` and in my development.rb I have put `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }` **Note that I'm currently using cloud 9 ide for this project.** The error occurs when I also try to migrate my database, also, I get the same error trying to run `rails g devise:install` Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run bundler after putting `gem 'devise'` on your Gemfile run `bundle install` details [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started) very nicely described you can follow this step by step.

Hope to help

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives me the same error once I run bundle install.

Comment: I never got it to work. :/ It was one of the projects (Create a reddit-like website) from Mackenzie Child's 12 and 12 challenge.

Comment: did you able to make it work @iiRosie1 you marked as answer, how did you solved it